# xero oauth/Authorize showing login page instead of asking for access

Tags: url, authentication, postman, xero-api

I went though the developer documentation on xero https://developer.xero.com/documentation/auth-and-limits/public-applications which I was stuck with then I found a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzZpgSHdKfU which is quite nice but then I got stuck when it's showing how to use the `https://api.xero.com/oauth/Authorize`.

I am using `postman` as testing as I am totally new with xero.
It I did the `requestToken` api which worked fine and got the oauth_token but the video showed going to browser and go `https://api.xero.com/oauth/Authorize` would actually show the page of application not found and url would be redirect as something like `https://app.xero.com/oauth/APIAuthorise?oauth_token=` but instead I got redirect to a login page with url of `https://login.xero.com/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fapp.xero.com&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252foauth%252fAPIAuthorise%253foauth_token%253d&wct=2019-06-06T22%3a48%3a18Z&oauth_token=`  I tried adding the `oauth_token` at the end of the url which does not work at all.

Still asking me to login

Anyone has had this kind of situation happening?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To authorise/connect an app to Xero, the user needs to log in to Xero and choose one of their Xero organisations to connect. To authorise your app, if you are the test user, you will need a Xero account (start a 30-day trial and use the demo company). https://www.xero.com/signup/